# Moving the words of the read line into an array of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I made the program read the line I want from a text file. Now the problem arises that I don't know how to place the words in that line into a array of strings?

For example, program read specific line:

```
learning school student computer data book algorithm textbook text product article
```

How to fit the words of this line into an array of strings?

I have started something, but I don't understand how to do it.

```
if (dat.is_open())
{
    while (getline(dat, string))
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            d = stoi(string); //Here is something for line 1.
            g.n = d;
            count++;
        }
        else if (count == 1)
        {
            //What I don't understand here is how to go through the second line and put all the words of that line into an array of strings?
            string Text;
            int i = 0;
            while (i<string.length())
            {

                if (number_string[i] != ' ')
                {
                    Text += string[i];
                    
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by an "array of strings"? Do you mean an [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), i.e. `std::array<std::string> array;`? Or can it also be a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), i.e. `std::vector<std::string> vec;`? Or does it have to be a C-style array, i.e. `std::string array[100];`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use stringstream to extract individual words.

Example:

```
 stringstream ss(line);

 vector<string> words;

 // Extract each word from the stringstream and add it to the vector.
 string word;
 while (ss >> word)
 {
      words.push_back(word);
 }
```

Comment: No need to use a loop. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @sinanorl you can use a stringstream. But you don't need another loop. You can use iterators into the stream to simply initialize the vector.

```
 stringstream ss(line);

 vector<string> words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss), std::istream_iterator<std::string>{});
```

But if I read your code correctly. It seems like only the first line is special. After that all words should be copied into the array.

```
 // Assuming that the first line is special.
 // Let us read the first line then extract the first number from that line.
 std::string                line1;
 if (!getline(dat, line1))
 {
     // We Failed to read the first line.
     throw std::runtime_error("Failed to get line");
 }
 // Get the number from the first line.
 g.n = stoi(string);

 std::vector<std::string>   words(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(dat), std::istream_iterator<std::string>{});
```

Note: The `std::istream_iterator<T>` will read one object of type `T` from the stream using the `operator>>`. This is great for numbers as it makes it really easy to read a file of numbers into a vector.

When `T` is a `std::string` it uses the same `operator>>` to read the stream. Here though when you read a stream into a string it reads one space separated word. i.e. it ignores leading white space then reads a word stopping at the next white space. So this technique will read a file of words into a vector.